# RangeIndex with non-integer step

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Is there a pandas Index subclass like RangeIndex that allows non-integer step sizes?  Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=.1)  # TypeError: Wrong type <class 'float'> for value 0.1
```

The classes listed in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) do not appear adequate.  IntervalIndex handles arbitrary ranges but does not explicitly store a step size (which I intend to access later in my code).

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a [`Float64Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Float64Index.html), there is however no parameter to define the start/stop/step.

Best is likely to use [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
idx = pd.Index(np.arange(0,10,0.1))
```

output (rounded for display):

```
Float64Index([ 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
               1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  2.0,
               2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  3.0,  3.0,  3.0,  3.0,  3.0,  3.0,  3.0,
               3.0,  3.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,  4.0,
               4.0,  4.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,
               6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,  6.0,
               7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  7.0,  8.0,  8.0,
               8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  8.0,  9.0,  9.0,
               9.0,  9.0,  9.0,  9.0,  9.0,  9.0,  9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0,
              10.0],
             dtype='float64')
```